# Centos 7: No Wifi Adapter found

Tags: linux, centos, networking, wifi

I have dual booted centos 7 with Windows 10. Once centos 7 setup finished, no wifi connection was available. In the "settings > Wifi", I see a message saying "No wifi adapter found".

My wifi adapter is '"roadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/Broadcom (unconfirmed reference) and https://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
su -
dhclient -v
ifconfig
```

Comment: Really worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. I opened terminal and I ran the following commands which worked in my case:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo rfkill list
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

Comment: what does this even do?

Answer (score -3):

Type `nmtui` on the terminal; it will pop-up a window where you can set SSI and BSSID in the WiFi connection.

Comment: How does this help when the OP said "`In the "settings > Wifi", I see a message saying "No wifi adapter found".`"?